# Limit the codomain of a function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\a{5}
    \draw[->] (-\a,0) -- (+\a,0);
    \draw[->] (0,-\a) -- (0,+\a);
    \draw[thick, red,  samples=100, domain=-.7:3.2] plot ({\x},{ \x*\x*(1-\x)*(3-\x) });   
    \def\E{2}
    \draw[thick, green] (-\a,\E) -- (+\a,\E) node[xshift=0.5cm] {$ E $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

and I have this output

[image]

How to limit the codomain range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a dedicated plotting package built on `tikz` namely, `pgfplots`.  One implementation of your plot in that could be:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-.7:3.2, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, ticks=none,
    enlarge x limits={rel=0.07}]
    \addplot[thick, red, samples=100] {(x*x*(1-x)*(3-x))};
    \addplot[green] {(.5)} node[right]{$E$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can move the codomain restrictions to just the one function, but putting them as options to the `\addplot` command, but you have to use the option

```
restrict y to domain=-1:1
```

and to get the cut-off right in your example you then have to increase the number of samples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-.7:3.2,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, ticks=none,
    enlarge x limits={rel=0.07}]
    \addplot[thick, red, samples=5000, restrict y to domain=-1:1] {(x*x*(1-x)*(3-x))};
    \addplot[green] {(.5)} node[right]{$E$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want to control the axis lengths precisely, use `xmin`/`xmax`/`ymin`/`ymax` and adjust the domains on the individual plots:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, ticks=none]
    \addplot[thick, red, samples=5000,
      domain=-.7:3.2, restrict y to domain=-1:1] {(x*x*(1-x)*(3-x))};
    \addplot[domain=-5:4.2, green] {(.5)} node[right]{$E$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `restrict y to domain=a:b` is probably more what the OP wants.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I used that initially, but found it was clipping at the wrong places, perhaps because it requires more samples...

Comment: True, that can be a problem.

Comment: So there is no way to restric only the plot of the function?

Comment: Yes, just put the options (either `restrict y to domain` or `ymin`/`ymax`) in the `\addplot` command rather than the `axis`, if that is what you want.

Comment: You can't use `ymin`/`ymax` in an `\addplot`, that will give you `! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't change 'ymin' in this context. Maybe
 you need to provide it as \begin{axis}[ymin=...] ?.`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Many thanks - though I had tested it, but you are right.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you guys but my purpose is only to limit the output of `\draw[thick, red,  samples=100, domain=-.7:3.2] plot ({\x},{ \x*\x*(1-\x)*(3-\x) });` to some y domain. One solution is to use the brain every time. For instance I only need to restric the 'domain' each time.  I whish there is a `ymin,ymax` version for `\draw[ , ymin=??, ymax=??] ... plot` because in this solution it seems that I can t control the axis.

Comment: There are many ways to control the axis in the above coding.  What do you wish to change?

Comment: Can I control the axis lenght? like this? `\def\a{5} \draw[->] (-\a,0) -- (+\a,0); \draw[->] (0,-\a) -- (0,+\a);`

Comment: Yes, see update to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`\clip`? The purpose of the `scope` environment is to localize the effect of the `\clip`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\a{5}
  \def\E{2}
  \draw[->] (-\a,0) -- (+\a,0);
  \draw[->] (0,-\a) -- (0,+\a);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-\a,-\a) rectangle (\a,\E);
    \draw[thick, red,  samples=100, domain=-.7:3.2] plot ({\x},{ \x*\x*(1-\x)*(3-\x) });
  \end{scope}
  \draw[thick, green] (-\a,\E) -- (+\a,\E) node[xshift=0.5cm] {$ E $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you but I prefer some solution like `\draw[thick, red,  samples=100, domain=-.7:3.2, codomain = somerange: somerange]`

Comment: @AndreaLeo `pgfplots` (see Andrew's answer) and its `restrict y to domain` key perhaps. I don't know at the moment how to do that, though others might come up with something.

Comment: @AndreaLeo You could always wrap the `scope`, `\clip` and `\draw` into one `\newcommand`, if you must do this in one line of code.